# Virtualbox Drag and Drop not working, freezes at "Dropping Data 0%"

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, drag-and-drop

I've enabled Drag & Drop in Virtualbox, and I tried dragging a small file from host to guest (both are win7).

I get this dialog:

[image]

And it stays at 0% forever.

How can I fix this and make Drag and Drop work?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, after restarting the VM, and also killing and restarting Explorer, drag&drop was working again. I have no idea why it stopped working or why the restart helped.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new file with a *.`ps1` extension, and save the following PowerShell script to that file. Then when this issue occurs, click cancel(the red X), then run the script, and try the copy again. [Script obtained from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/790925/247842):

```
echo "Trying to restart VBoxClient"

$vbox_process = Get-Process VBoxTray
Write-verbose $vbox_process
$procID = $vbox_process.id

if ($procID  -gt 0)
{    
    $cmdline = (Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -Filter "Handle=$procID").CommandLine
    Write-Verbose $cmdline

    Write-Verbose "Stopping VBoxTray"
    $vbox_process.Kill()
    $vbox_process.WaitForExit()
    Write-Verbose "VBoxTray stopped"

    Write-Verbose "Starting VBoxTray"
    Start-Process -FilePath $cmdline.Split(' ')[0]
    echo "VBoxTray Restarted. All Done"
} else {    
    Write-Warning 'Could not find existing vboxTray process. Launching direct?'
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\VBoxTray.exe"     
}
```

Comment: Also when this happens I've noticed that the handle on the file trying to be dropped isn't properly closed, so you might have to using something like [process explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to close the handle to that file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a linux guest, use this to try to re-enable drag and drop:

```
pkill -f VBoxClient; VBoxClient --draganddrop
```

Comment: Why are you copying same answer [twice](https://superuser.com/a/1702222/763386)?

Comment: 2022, this worked for me. I have no idea why another commented a complaint. Thank you!